# What with v-main can i delete it?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

What is the big purple square on the bottom how can i delete it?
[image]

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
  <template>
      <header>
        <div>
          <Header v-if="!$route.meta.hideHeader" />
        </div>
      </header>
      <router-view/>
    </template>

<template>
      <footer>
        <div>
          <Footer v-if="!$route.meta.hideFooter" />
        </div>
      </footer>
</template>
  </v-app>
</template>
```

here is my app.vue
i think app.vue made it maybe i need to add v-main? and whatI have to pass there

Maybe it might be looking like this??

```html
<template>
  <v-app>

    <template>
    <header>
        <div>
          <Header v-if="!$route.meta.hideHeader" />
        </div>
      </header>
    <router-view/>
  </template>

    <v-main>
   </v-main>

    <template>
      <footer>
        <div>
          <Footer v-if="!$route.meta.hideFooter" />
        </div>
      </footer>
  </template>

  </v-app>
</template>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The purple box in your screenshot is a flexbox overlay (part of Chrome's [Flexbox debugging tools](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-90/#flexbox) added in Chrome 90), [which shows the available space in the box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67252231/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-purple-dashed-line-area).

For the app contents to fill the available space, use `v-main` around the main content. The [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application/#default-application-markup) recommend the following layout for an app that matches your example (with a header, main, router view, and footer):

```html
<v-app>
  <v-navigation-drawer app>
    <!-- -->
  </v-navigation-drawer>

  <v-app-bar app>
    <!-- -->
  </v-app-bar>

  <!-- Sizes your content based upon application components -->
  <v-main>

    <!-- Provides the application the proper gutter -->
    <v-container fluid>

      <!-- If using vue-router -->
      <router-view></router-view>
    </v-container>
  </v-main>

  <v-footer app>
    <!-- -->
  </v-footer>
</v-app>
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-v-app-example-uobps?file=/src/App.vue)

Comment: yes thanks but i think the reason for this is v-parallax, the image size is the reason for this white spot, thank you very much
When i deleted the v-parallax the white spot ("v-main") disappeared

Comment: I don't see `v-parallax` used in the markup shown in the question.