# In Chrome Element inspector, what does a blue field with diagonal dashed purple lines indicate?

Tags: css

I cannot decipher this UI . . . why this element is 100% height regardless of the set styles. Is there a  key anywhere that explains all of  Chrome's  inspector styles? Mainstay ones like  padding and margin are clear, but this is an odd one. [image: inspector field shading]

Nothing strange to see here:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Stackoverflow side navigation bar is just like that.

Another reply on Stackoverflow says is expandable spaces.

But i recommend you using the element inspector to see more details. Probably is a container element that has elements inside but have room for more.

[image]
[image]

Check here for more info: [What is the purpose of this purple dashed line area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67252231/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-purple-dashed-line-area)

Answer (score 0):

It the area spanned by that element , if give a `background-color` property you can see that whole blue area is covered by background-color .

> Unless you have given a border-radius than also the blue area color remain same but background-color will have border-radius property)

You must have hovered over the parent-element of your search , this is the reason of covering whole area . If you have given code than it will be easy to show the effect .

[Here is more about Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/overview/)