# Purple lines / Conditionnal rendering

Tags: css, reactjs

I have those purple lines ( as my screen bellow ).

I doing some conditionnal rendering, I'd like to know if I can remove all those **purple lines**.

I've heard removing all divs and adding React.Fragments might help, this what I've done so far. But the issue is still there.

If anyone could tell where the issue might come from, I'd be grateful !

[image]

**the main view / Render 1**

```
<div className="user-infos">
  <h4><u> Parameters </u></h4>
  { (componentState == "edit") ?
    <form > 
      <Render 3/>
    </form>
  : (componentState == "index") ?
     <Render 2/>
  : (componentState == "delete") ? 
     <React.Fragment>
        <p> Are you sure you want to leave us ? </p>
        <p> If yes, you have to type your email and press "confirm".</p>         
        <form>
          <input type="text" />
          <input type="submit" value="confirm email"/>
        </form>
        <span>
          <button> Delete ur account</button>
          <button> Cancel </button>
        </span>
      </React.Fragment>
    : ""
    }
  </div>
```

**Render 2**

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>

        <p> Username : John </p>
        <p> Timezone : London </p>

        <span>
        <button> Edit Profile </button>
        <button> Delete account </<button>>
        </span>

    </React.Fragment>
```

**Render 3**

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
    
        <label for="email"> Username : 
          <input type="text"/>
        </label>

        <label for="text"> Timezone :
          <span>
          <select        
            onChange={options}        
          <options>
          </select>
          </span>
        </label>
     
        <button type="submit"> Save Profile </button>
        <button> Cancel </button>

    </React.Fragment>
  );
```

Comment: Can you add your CSS as well?

Answer (score 0):

By default, chrome adds styling to your html. In the case of `<p>`, it adds the following css to your element.

[image: chrome user agent stylesheet]

If you want the margin to disappear, you need to set `margin: 0;` on your `<p>` element to overwrite chrome's styling.

Answer (score 0):

The purple dash line occurs when there is available space for the elements to expand into. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67252231/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-purple-dashed-line-area). From what I can tell from comparing flexboxes with other `display` types, the purple dash with purple background is specifically for space inside flexboxes (`display:flex` in CSS).

Would need to see your CSS to be sure, but I imagine there's `justify-content: space-between` telling the flexbox to evenly distribute the remaining empty space between the elements as well as `flex-direction: column` telling the flexbox to stack the child elements vertically.

If that's the case, you can remove `justify-content: space-between` and use flexbox styling to change things to how you want it to look. I found this website helpful: [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](http://%20https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)