# What is the purpose of this purple arrow in browser dev tool?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

[image: inspecting an element shows a solid arrow]

What is the purpose of this arrow? I know about the dashed line area thanks to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67252231/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-purple-dashed-line-area) but I don't know what the arrow is.

Here is a reproducible example:

```css
 .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        background-color: grey;
        width: 50px;
    }

    .item {
        height: 84px;
        width: 112px;

    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's the direction in which flex grows/shrinks.

Comment: With the dashed area what does it mean? How can I have white space like that? @wOxxOm

Comment: The dashed area is probably the initial size e.g. flex-basis or the actual content. Show an [MCVE](/help/mcve).

Comment: @wOxxOm I updated the post. You need to zoom in to make the arrow appears

Comment: I don't see the arrow regardless of zooming. Please embed a live snippet with [MCVE](/help/mcve) in the question.

Comment: I don't see the arrow either; all I see is https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHYAb.png

Comment: BTW, you can reduce the amount of code by using shorthand: `display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap; background: gray`.

Comment: Here is a crazy useful article if you wanna know everything about flex and to eat it:
https://bocoup.com/blog/dive-into-flexbox

Answer (score 6):

The arrow simply shows when there is no space for an item to take it's full size in a flex layout in the direction of the main axis. It will show horizontally if the flex-direction was set to row and vertically if it is set to column.

It doesn't show in your example by default because there is enough space for the item to take its full size, but if we set the width of the container's to a lower value than its children, then this arrow will show up to tell us that this item is supposed to be in a certain size but there is no space. Here is an updated version of your example that shows the arrows in both directions, when the container's width and height are lower than its children's. I also added another container as a ruler to see that it does match the arrow.

[image]

here is the updated code:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  background-color: grey;
  width:50px;
}

.item {
  height: 84px;
  width: 112px;
}
.container2{
  width:1000px;
}
.ruler{
  width:112px;
  background:green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="container2 c2">
  <div class="item ruler">112px</div>
</div>
```

This arrow can be shown when working with flex-basis which is used to set the initial main size of a flex item, before any remaining space is distributed among the flex items according to their flex-grow and flex-shrink values.If the flex-basis property is not specified, it is set to auto by default.

See the [MDN documentation illustration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis), when the flex item is set to a value by either (flex-basis or width or height) but it doesn't take flex-size completely.
This happens when the container's size along the main axis is not sufficient for the flex items in it, so this arrow appears to show the complete size of a flex item if there were a space for it.

And here is an example that shows that
[image]

and here the container is set to flex-column and its height is 100px, but its child item is set to flex-basis is set to 200px which means that the item needs additional 100px.
[image]

The code for the above images

```css
    .container {
        display: flex;
        /* flex-direction: row; */
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        background-color: grey;
    }

    .item {
        height: 84px;
        width: 112px;

    }

    .i1 {
        background-color: red;
        flex-basis: 500px;
    }

    .i2 {
        background-color: green;
        flex-basis: 700px;
    }

    .i3 {
        background-color: blue;
        flex-basis: 800ox;
    }

    .ruler {
        width: 500px;
        background-color: black;
    }

    .c2 {
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 100px;
    }

    .item4 {
        background-color: yellow;
        flex-basis: 200px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item i1"></div>
    <div class="item i2"></div>
    <div class="item i3"></div>
</div>
<div class="ruler">
    a
</div>

<div class="container c2">
    <div class="item item4"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've actually seen the arrow when a flex item has grown because of padding, even with width, height, max-width, max-height, min-height, min-width set and `flex: 0 0 0;`